# What dialects use だべ？

Tags: particles, dialects

I feel like I hear だべ all the time (through TV and on the streets of Yokohama where I live), but I'm wondering about it's origins and modern usage.

Comment: The title and your question seem to be slightly different.

Comment: ah but they are intrinsically linked. What it meant in one time and location and what it means in modern times and locations is all related to dialect, I feel.

Comment: I can tell you that the origin is classical Japanese べし (or some common predecessor), but I'd be interested to read a history showing how we got from there to modern べ (which is why I got the easy part out of the way in a comment).

Answer (score 4):

It's Tohoku dialect.

Basically, だべ is だろう, 行ぐべ is 行こう.
There are a lot of variations though, as you can say for example だすっぺ for でしょう.

I doubt though that your hear that a lot on TV, except during interviews of people who suffers from the tsunami or nuclear accident.  And it would be subtitled anyway…

Edit: Ok, so it seems that だべ is in fact an "coastal" ending.  This is why your heard it in Yokohama, while in didn't where I lived.  It's used all along the Pacific coast, and is thus not restricted to Tôhoku.  I do not know, though, if they use べ without だ as in the examples I gave.

Comment: To be precise, it's Tōhoku and Kantō dialect (they even call our accent/us "Kantō-bei"! classic West/East divide thing), but it has definitely suffered a blow in the Tokyo region due to the influence of 標準語 and people from other prefectures. Still a thing in the surrounding areas though, like Saitama etc.

Comment: I have lived in Kanagawa-ken too, and never heard it there… Nor in Tôkyô, even from Tôhoku people…  How old are Kantô people talking with this particle?

Comment: In (northern) Saitama, all ages. I confess I hear it a lot less in Kanagawa, and mostly (but not entirely) from older folks. I imagine that it's probably better preserved in Tohoku because of less outside influence.

Comment: I think it's because Saitama borders Gunma, Tochigi (Ashinori-ben, not mainstream Tochigi-ben) and Ibaraki, where usage such dialect is more prominent (Gunma has だんべ). The southern part of Saitama is more similar to that of southern part of Kantō (Tokyo, Chiba, Kanagawa).

Comment: It's Tohoku dialect.では
(Touhoku「東北」)ですか？？Northern most six prefectures of Honshuの方言ですか?

Comment: @axioplase I can specifically recall overhearing young brothers using it with each other here. But perhaps they were on a trip from somewhere else. 

Dabe just seems to be floating around in the background when I am about...

Comment: Also used in 北海道, even in cities like Sapporo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe べ is the equivalent of the volitional in some, usually considered rural, northern dialects.

For instance, いぐべ = 行こう (with a systematic voicing thrown in for a good measure) of [Miyagi-ben](http://miyagiajet.tripod.com/miyagi-ben03.html).

You can also see ["Tohoku Dialects as a Speech of Rednecks: Language Crossing in Japanese TV Programs"](http://ir.lib.shizuoka.ac.jp/bitstream/10297/5474/1/110214001.pdf).

Comment: Nice article on crossing.