# What does the phrase 「ああなんだべか」mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases, video-games

I came across this phrase from a video game.

After having a discussion, a boy named ナムジン left from the place and a guy who still remained there with others said this sentence.

> はあ  ナムジンさま　どうして **ああなんだべか**…。

For my understanding, ああ means 'like that' so the phrase would probably mean 'doing something like that'.

Is it related to a certain dialect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What dialects use だべ？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/what-dialects-use-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%b9) どうしてああなんだべか = どうしてああなんだろうか = "I wonder why he is like that..."